# Prove that three rectangles intersect if they intersect pairwisely

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

Given three axis-parallel (open) rectangles in the plane, if they are pairwise intersected (intersect means share at least one point), how to prove that the THREE rectangles intersect? Can we do this algebraically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axis-parallel rectangles intersect exactly if their projections onto each 
coordinate axis intersect. Therefore it is sufficient to show that
if $n$ open intervals $(a_i, b_i)$ have pairwise non-empty intersection then
their intersection $\cap_{i=1}^n (a_i, b_i)$ is nonempty.

So let $(a_i, b_i)$, $i=1, \ldots, n$ be intervals with pairwise non-empty
intersection.

Let $ A := \max \{ a_1, \ldots a_n \}$ and $ B := \min \{ b_1, \ldots b_n \}$.
Then $A = a_k$ for some $k$ and $B = b_l$ for some $l$.
The intersection of $(a_k, b_k)$ with $(a_l, b_l)$ is non-empty. Choose
any $x \in (a_k, b_k) \cap (a_l, b_l)$. Then
$$
  \max \{ a_1, \ldots a_n \} = A = a_k < x  < b_l = B = \min \{ b_1, \ldots b_n \}
$$
which means that $x$ is contained in *all* intervals 
$(a_i, b_i)$ so that their total intersection is not empty.

Comment: Thanks, Martin! That's very helpful!